# Parse Vertical Tab Encoding Character Present in XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I am dealing with a legacy system that produces an XML from input. This input sometimes contains *vertical tab* control characters. These characters then get encoded in the resulting XML. The vertical tab can be written in a Java string as `\u000B`. Here's an example code illustrating what happens (the original process takes the string from the input, and creates the text nodes without any preprocessing):

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<xml></xml>")));
    Element sample = doc.createElement("sample");
    sample.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Hello\u000BWorld"));
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(sample);

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8")));
```

This produces an XML document, which is invalid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xml>
    <sample>Hello&#11;World</sample>
</xml>
```

Now I need to use the same parser, i.e.:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(theResultFromAbove)));
```

And produce the Document instance again. But this fails with:

```
[Fatal Error] :2:23: Character reference "&#
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 23; Character reference "&#
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
```

I have control of the second parser, so I can search&replace the `&#11;` before it parses the output. I have also some control of the code that produces the XML in the first place, so I can simply remove the vertical tabs before all of this happens.

However is there something I could do to *add* or *implement* the `&#11;` entity so the parser would not only encode it, but also decode it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you, but changing the XML version from 1.0 to 1.1 opens up the list of valid characters to include all control characters except for `0x00`, thus making the document containing `0x0B` or `VT` valid.

To set the version to 1.1, add the following configuration to the transformer:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.1");
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question perfectly. Not on to search for newly introduced bugs...